# Transfer all files from FTP server to Artifactory Generic repo

Tags: ftp, artifactory

I have an FTP server which has a lot of files (almost 400 GB) in it following a particular directory structure. But I got a requirement to migrate from FTP to Jfrog artifactory. Is there any way to copy the entire files under this FTP server to Jfrog artifactory **Generic type** repository with preserving the folder structure used in FTP.

I tried deploying as an archive from UI (basically using REST API). But there is a limit that we can upload them as chunks of 100MB and it became tedious for me to follow this approach.

Can anyone suggest the other better way (command line or programmatic way or REST way) to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the [Repository Import](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ImportRepositoryContent) REST API:

```
POST /api/import/repositories?repo=<repository name>&path=<location in filesystem>
```

This should copy the folder structure and files at `path` into `repo`. Of course for this to work, your FTP content must be visible from Artifactory's filesystem.

Comment: But my ftp server and artifactory are hosted on different servers. In that case how to make this work?

Comment: @VishnuLakkimsetty As far as I know, there are ways to mount/access an FTP share as if it were a filesystem. See [FTPFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPFS).

Comment: I tried the POST call as you suggested from the folder where FTP is mounted. But I got this below error.

POST /api/import/repositories?repo=testrepo&path=/net/slc12ipc/scratch/apache-ftpserver-1.1.1/res/home
[1] 119495
bash-4.1$ Please enter content (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) to be POSTed:

I'm not sure what else it is expecting

Comment: You're probably best off using the [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) command, like so: `curl -u <username>:<password> -X POST "https://<artifactory domain>/artifactory/api/import/repositories?repo=testrepo&path=/net/slc12ipc/scratch/apache-ftpserver-1.1.1/res/home"`

Comment: which username and password I need to provide?? FTP or Artifactory?

Comment: An Artifactory admin user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JFrog CLI to upload entire directory to Artifactory
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=53577563

So in your case the only requirement is that the FTP server can connect to Artifactory over HTTP/HTTPS.

Then you just need to download JFrog CLI to FTP server and upload your files:

`jfrog rt u "path_to_files/*" my-local-repo/ftp_copy`